# Is there any framework like SFSpeechRecognizer in tvOS?

Tags: speech-recognition, tvos, sirikit, tvos10, sfspeechrecognizer

I want to build an app for tvOS which will recognise voice and convert it into text and based on that text it will perform some actions. I have already done that in iOS 10 using **SFSpeechRecognizer** class of  **Speech** Framework. I could not found any framework for tvOS.

Comment: I am not sure if now there is a public API for tvOS10 to work with microphone.

Comment: Any news/changes on this? I want to do the same.